# Stop counting after today date passed in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a column on Google sheets with different dates, I made a dashboard where you can see the upcoming rows with dates within 5 days away from today. It's a box saying "Starting within 5 days" and shows how many rows starts within 5 days. I made it work, the problem is that once we reached the date and passed it, it keeps counting it.

Let's say a row have a cell with the date 2022-10-20 and today is 2022-10-21, that means it already passed the date, so it should stop counting it. It should only count as "1" if the date set in a cell is within 5 days from todays date.

I hope I was clear enough, I use currently  `=COUNTIF('Under arbete'!C2:C; "<" & today()+5)`

Answer (score 0):

your formula

> `=COUNTIF('Under arbete'!C2:C; "<" & today()+5)`

will work only today. every next day it will be offset by +1 day because `TODAY` will "recalculate" on a daily basis

you can either feed it today's date like:

```
=COUNTIF('Under arbete'!C2:C; "<"&"2022-10-20"+5)
```

or try to freeze today's date like:

```
=COUNTIF('Under arbete'!C2:C; "<"&LAMBDA(x; x)(TODAY()+5))
```

---

### update:

```
=COUNTIFS(Kommande!C2:C; ">="&TODAY(); 
          Kommande!C2:C; "<"&TODAY()+10)
```

for multiple sheets:

```
=COUNTIFS({Kommande!C2:C; Sheet2!C2:C}; ">="&TODAY(); 
          {Kommande!C2:C; Sheet2!C2:C}; "<"&TODAY()+10)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer!

It's ok to recalculate; all I need for it to do is to not count the cells with dates that passed "today's" date, doesn't matter if today is tomorrow or any other day.

Once the date set in a cell passes today's date it should stop counting. And start counting once the date comes in within the 5 days from "today's" date which currently with my formula it works.

Have any ideas? :/

Comment: @AyKay if your initial formula is not working check if the dates in C column are valid with ISDATE

Comment: It does work, the problem is that it keeps counting as "1" even after the date passes "today"

The cell it pulls data from has a date, everytime today comes within 5 days of that date it starts counting. Let's say one cell has 2022-10-20 (which is two days from now), that means it counts it as "1", now let's say 3 days passes by which would be  Friday (from the time of writing this), that's the 21st, so we passed the date that was pulled from the cell, it should go back to "0" because there is no more date upcoming within 5 days.

Comment: Think of it as like a subscription, once it's 5 days away from your subscription payment, it counts "1" out of the whole column and pulls data from the cells "C2:C"

Now when that date passes by, it should stop counting that and go back to "0" as the date already passed

Comment: @AyKay can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Hey, yes of course: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hhS5tGK5ZcYOWB9_w8AdcCKqZi0fTysoEl-MYLEjtGA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: On the first tab, you will see the "dashboard" named "översikt".
Column K is where the numbers are, and the formula is in K7 and K10.

I added some comments to the sheet to make it easier for you.
I appreciate the help!

Comment: @AyKay try in K7: `=COUNTIFS(Kommande!C2:C; ">="&TODAY(); Kommande!C2:C; "<"&TODAY()+10)`

Comment: It worked! Thank you!!
Any idea if there is possibility to pull the same data from multiple tabs or is it only able to pull it from one tab? For example the C column on all the tabs?

Comment: @AyKay yes that is possible too. see the last formula from updated answer